# App crash while using CFrealese

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios6

[image: App crash here as shown in screenshot]

I am calling a method on background thread.. written below

```
   imageRef = assetLbraryImp.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;
   [self saveBigImageFull:imageRef withName:mediafileName addToAlbum:isFromCamera];

   -(void)saveBigImageFull:(CGImageRef)bigImage withName:(NSString*)imageName addToAlbum:   (BOOL)addToAlbum{
         bigImageFulldata = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: imageName, [NSNumber  numberWithBool:addToAlbum], nil];
[self saveBigImage:bigImageFulldata :bigImage];
 }
 -(void)saveBigImage:(id)data:(CGImageRef)imageRefere{
     _iName = (NSString *)[data objectAtIndex:0] ;
     bigImagefileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", _iName] ;
    bigImageFilepath = [photoPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:bigImagefileName] ;
   [self savePhotoBig:imageRefere toPath:bigImageFilepath];
 }

   -(void)savePhoto:(CGImageRef)photo toPath:(NSString *)path{
       image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:photo];
       imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
       [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
       if(photo)
            CFRelease(photo);
   }
```

but the app crash because of CFRelease. when i remove CFRelease then the code is working fine.. if am saving 100 images then 100 images gets saved. even after saving in the end app crash. the app crash at the end of process  not in between.

any idea?

Comment: could you post the exact crash log in the console? does the crash happen on CFRelease or elsewhere (i.e., *after* it)?

Comment: there is no log in console regarding this crash

Comment: you mean there is not log when `CFRelease` is there or when you remove it?

Comment: added screenshot regarding crash..

Comment: Try turning on "zombie objects" (google for it if you're not sure how); it will probably give you more information. Also, the code you posted doesn't include a call to the method you say is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

> the app crash because of CFRelease. when i remove CFRelease then the code is working fine.

I would suggest checking what you do with `photo` in the method that calls `savePhoto:`; are you accessing `photo` after calling `savePhoto:`?

> if am saving 100 images then 100 images gets saved. even after saving in the end app crash.

I assume this to be a memory fill-up problem. Check your app with Instruments' memory allocation tool to confirm it's being killed due to memory fill-up.

EDIT:

Reading your code above, it seems that you are saving the following image:

```
imageRef = assetLbraryImp.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;
```

this is the same image that you later release through `CFRelease`. Here 2 things:

1. possibly assetLibraryImp is the actual owner of the image, so you better let it do the release (but I cannot judge this from your code, so you will know);
2. if you want to do the release in `savePhoto`, then I really do think you should use `CGImageRelease` instead of `CFRelease`, i.e.:

   ```
     if(photo)
          CGImageRelease(photo);
   ```

Furthermore, you say that you are executing that method in a background thread: please, be aware that UIKit is not thread safe, so it is highly likely that this is the reason of your crash. Try and execute that method on the main thread (although it will block the UI, just for a test) and see what happens.

Comment: yes i am accessing these images imidiatly after saving ten into document directory.. is this case with document directory? do i need to use cache directory for it?

Comment: but i am not accessing photo in savePhoto method. i am accessing photo in another view.

Comment: this error even occurs when i try to save 1 or 2 photos .. its not the issue only in case of to many images.. app crash even for 2  images

Comment: can you show how you create `photo` before passing it into `savePhoto`?

Comment: the crash picture shows that your app is dying in SavedImageViewController layXYZ method. can you paste its content?

Comment: updated the question please check it if u can figure out the problem.. and one thing the crash occur only if i dnt load "SavedImageViewController" view so i think problem is not in "SavedImageViewControlle" view but i am reading the images in "SavedImageViewControlle" and showing then  in uiimage.. if u want whole code then plz send me ur Emailid so that i can send to the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24666/discussion-between-kanwar-and-sergio)

Comment: sorry, I had left the chat for a while. please, see my last comment there.